# Find multiple string matches from the original string batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-interface

I currently have a list of files in a folder that i need to iterate through and exclude the non production files that matches the pattern. how do i search for multiple strings in a batch command?

for example i have files as

- QA_test_1.txt
- QA_809_test.txt
- dev_93439_sd.txt
- stg_abc_sldkf_df.txt
- prod_4845_sdfd.txt
- prod_998_sdfd.txt
- live_lskd_sd3434.txt
- xyz_sdfdf_s3rer.txt

from the list above i need to exclude every file that has the word "dev", QA  "Stg" and generate a list of files without them - which is

- prod_4845_sdfd.txt
- prod_998_sdfd.txt
- live_lskd_sd3434.txt
- xyz_sdfdf_s3rer.txt

The problem is - i am not able to find any batch command that can do a grep equivalent for multiple strings. FindStr does it only for one string and hence i am not able to get that working. here is code that i have

```
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A /S Path *.txt') do (
   set /A i+=1
rem put the file names in array
   set list[!i!]=%%~na
rem try to find the file names 
echo %%~na|find "dev" or "qa" or "stg" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found %%~na )
  
)
```

Comment: `findstr "string1 string2 string3 string4"` will find any of the 4 strings. `findstr /c:"string1" /c;"string2" /c:"string3" /c:"string4"` likewise, or you can put the strings into a file, 1 to a line and use `findstr /g:filename` to do the same thing.

Comment: You are talking about the beginning of the file names to match, right?

Comment: No it can be in between as well

Comment: If you are looking to parse the list and exclude certain file names, you could string together findstr /v options, like findstr /v "dev" | findstr /v "QA | findstr /v "Stg"

Comment: What about occurrence of something like `stgs`? is this considered as a match (due to search term `stg`) or not?

Comment: The simple solution is running __DIR__ and use __FINDSTR__ as filter. So run `dir "C:\Folder\With The\Text Files\*.txt" /A-D /ON /B 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V "dev QA Stg"`. Please note that case-insensitive `dev` __OR__ `QA` __OR__ `Stg` are not explicitly interpreted as __word__. The usage of `\<` (beginning of a word) and `\>` (end of a word) cannot be used in this case because of `_` is also a word character and therefore `QA_test_1` is one word for the regular expression function in __FINDSTR__.

Comment: There can be used `dir "C:\Folder\With The\Text Files\*.txt" /A-D /ON /B 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V "^dev[_.] [_.]dev[_.] ^QA[_.] [_.]QA[_.] ^Stg[_.] [_.]Stg[_.]"` to filter out all file names containing case-insensitive `dev` __OR__ `QA` __OR__ `Stg` at beginning of the file name with an underscore or a dot as next character or between underscores or dots.

Comment: If you want to process further the filtered list of file names use `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Folder\With The\Text Files\*.txt" /A-D /ON /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V "^dev[_.] [_.]dev[_.] ^QA[_.] [_.]QA[_.] ^Stg[_.] [_.]Stg[_.]"') do echo "C:\Folder\With The\Text Files\%%I"` with replacing the command `echo` by whatever command to execute with the current file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the response.
I was able to do it below way

```
echo %%~na|findstr /i /v "dev QA Stg" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not found %%~na) else (echo %%~na>>newfile.txt)
```